# Where should I ask about translation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a community to ask about translation, especially about Hebrew translation?

I didn't find any community that I can ask about such translation tools or general inquiries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any Translation.SE, unfortunately. Translation question are sometimes on-topic on the various language sites (e.g., "please help me understand this complicated sentence..." or "what's a good word for XYZ" are usually OK, "please translate War and Peace and share here" usually aren't), but unfortunately we don't have a Hebrew language site either. There have been a couple of attempts to propose one on Area 51 which did not succeed, and the current attempt there is to create a [Semtiic Languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113173/semitic-languages?referrer=SkqGiQRofKEBmqgt1wfCkA2) site, which you could join and help push forward.

Comment: The link in now deleted - "This proposal has been deleted."